# SQL Server keys issue

Tags: sql-server

I am new at database design and I do have couple of questions to you guys how to create relational databases.

I have couple of questions:

Connecting `Table A` and `Table B` by a foreign key, where do I create a key in `Table A` or `B`?

Lets say I do have table `Users` and `Ranks` with a 1 : 1 relationship.

`Users` table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](89) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Midname] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Surname] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Phone] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Country] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Manager] [nvarchar](89) NOT NULL,
    [Referrer] [nvarchar](89) NOT NULL,
    [Rank] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT [PK_UsersID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
       ([Email] ASC)
    )
```

`Ranks` table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ranks](
    [ID] [tinyint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Rank] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_Rank] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
      ([ID] ASC)
    )
```

I want to join them by:

```
Users.Rank ON Rank.ID
```

But it doesn't allow me to create a key, I am getting such error:

> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> The columns in table 'Users' do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint.

Why does it telling me about ANY primary key? I am not touching a primary I am working with a foreign keys, I don't understand why PK and FK is related.

Could you please explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The reason for getting that error is Rank column in User table which you are trying to reference does not have unique or primary key on it

Comment: @marc_s, But I can't do Users.Rank as PK. How do I design my tables then? Is it okay if I am not going to connect them by FK?

Comment: Does KM.'s answer work for you? Create FK from `Users.Rank` -> `Rank.ID` ? I misread / misinterpreted your question

Comment: I can create `User.Rank` - > `Rank.ID` but I can't `Rank.ID -> `User.Rank`. Which one is right by design?

Comment: Maybe I can leave it even without FK? is it OK?

Answer (score 3):

I can create the foreign key using this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_Users_Ranks FOREIGN KEY
    (
    Rank
    ) REFERENCES dbo.Ranks
    (
    ID
    )
```

join them like:

```
select
    *
    from Users           u 
        INNER JOIN Ranks r ON u.rank=r.id
```

I recommend removing the `IDENTITY(1,1)` from Ranks.ID.  With so few values (tinyint) it is best to manage the IDs yourself.  You can insert ranks with IDs of 10, 20, 30, 40.  later on if you need you can add a 15 if you need to include a new one between 10 and 20.  With an identity, you are locked in.

Make sure that if you currently have data in your tables and try then to add the FK, that all the Users.Rank values exist within Rank.ID before adding the FK.

Comment: KM, I can connect `Users.Rank` - > `Rank.ID` but DELETE cascade is not working. I thought key has to be established opposite like: `Rank.ID` -> `Users.Rank`. Any ideas?

Comment: **why would you cascade a delete on users and ranks?**  would you ever want to delete a rank and remove all those users as well? or would you ever want to delete a user and remove that rank?

Comment: I don't want to cascade ranks deleting a user, just thinking about future. If I don't want to cascade it, what's the point connecting tables by FK such as `User.ID` - > `Rank.ID`

Comment: I have lots of FK, and have NEVER done a cascade delete (I prefer to use my own transaction to control all the deletes [validation and logging, etc.], or to use a soft delete).  To me, the main purpose of a FK is as a constraint.  It will guarantee that every User has a valid Rank value.  So when I join Users to rank, I know the INNER JOIN will not throw away any users because the user has a bogus rank value in it.

Comment: @WildGoat: Put simply, foreign keys are primarily about *data consistency*. Cascaded deletes and/or updates are secondary to that, presently you may consider them as a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

**Users.Rank ON Rank.ID** this is correct but  if Users.Rank is int, Rank.ID should be int too, or it will generate errors.

Primary key for persons is for example Personal ID, or email, or name+lastname+age or somthing else..., but in databases  this ID -is often integer type. 
if you have person table, you should have columns 
**personid, name, lastname, ... ,**

when you use that personid in another table it becomes foreign key. for ex.
if you have phonenumber table you wiil have these column

numberid, prefix, number, and **personid** - now this personid  is FK. **FK type = PK type**

you can do this in database diagram simply:
first drag by hand primary key field to the foreign key table:
[image: drag by hand primary key field to the foreign key table]
than

than look at the dialog and click ok :)
[image: enthan look at the dialog and click ok :)e]

Comment: aren't Users.Rank and Rank.ID both tinyints?

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating the foreign key in "the right direction"? Based on the error message I would venture to guess that you are trying to create relation where you:

- Select the primary key table to be Users, column to be Rank
- Select the foreign key table to be Rank, column to be ID

This means that the "key" Users.Rank will be exported to the Rank table, which is not possible since the Users.Rank columns is not a key for the Users table.

The foreign key should be in the other direction:

- Primary key table is Rank, column ID
- Foreign key table is Users, coulmn Rank

This will create a one-to-many key where meny rows in the Users table can have the same rank. If you really want to have a one-to-one relationship, you will have to create a unique index (or constraint) on the Users.Rank column.